# Google APIs or Qt Mobility

Tags: qt, google-maps, qt-mobility, google-api-client

I'm going to write a routing and navigation application for our company. I think I have two options . Google APIs and Nokia APIs through Qt Mobility ! I'm not sure which one I should use to reach better results. By better results I mean better integrity in my application that is going to be a desktop application. And If the answer is google APIs I'm not sure which one of google APIs I should use?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this is an interesting one, the Qt Mobility APIs hooking into the Nokia mapping stuff are available and would make your life easier but with the changes that have occurred recently with Nokia selling off Qt there's no guarantee that they'll still work in 6 months time. With the Google mapping APIs they're a bit more, well, stable.

Which Google API? Well, I'm not too up to speed on it, but as far as I know you can use the Javascript API and hook it into a QWebView which should be pretty straight forward.

Comment: Thank u but the problem with Google APIs is mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12070604/qwebkit-doesnt-handle-click-and-dblclick-for-google-maps) :)