# QWebKit doesn't handle click and dblclick for Google Maps

Tags: google-maps-api-3, qwebview, qwebkit

I just copy/pasted this code from google maps API in a my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <style type="text/css">
      html { height: 100% }
      body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
      #map_canvas { height: 100% }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript"
      src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MYKEY&sensor=false">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
          zoom: 8,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
            mapOptions);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="initialize()">
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Every things is OK in a browser like chrome. I mean when I double click on the map it zooms in. And When I drag the map the center point of the map changes. 
But when I load this file in a QWebView object, the map loads but QWebView doesn't pay attention to clicks and double clicks !

Comment: How have you created your WebView? Have you enabled Javascript and plugins?

Comment: Surly I've created a QWebView and Javascript is enabled! If it wasn't so I couldn't even load the map .

Comment: Ah I meant did you create it programmatically or through Qt Designer sorry.

Comment: It's created using designer! Is there any difference ?